# What is the CORRECT way to separate color HEX values from each other?

Tags: python, hex

I made a small Python program that renders an image by drawing pixels with a predefined color (in HEX values, which is important).

##### Input

I made a test HEX string that lists all blue values (it looks something like this: `"000000000001000002000003000004..."`)

But when I insert this line into my program, the color values jump around for some reason.

##### Expected

it should be something like this:

- (color picker #000000, brush down, 1 step, brush up),
- (color picker #000001, brush down, 1 step, brush up),
- (color picker #000002, brush down, 1 step, brush up), etc.

##### Actuel output

But in the program, for some reason, it is redone like this:

- (color picker #000000, brush down, 1 step, brush up),
- (color picker #000010, brush down, 1 step, brush up),
- (color picker #000200, brush down, 1 step, brush up),
- (color picker #003000, brush down, 1 step, brush up),
- (color picker #040000, brush down, 1 step, brush up)
- etc.

Can this be fixed so that the program works properly?

Full program code:

```
import turtle as tur

hexString = input('Введите HEX-строку БЕЗ пробелов: ')

tur.clear()
tur.penup()

startX = -380
startY = 320

tur.goto(startX, startY)

a = 0
hexColors = []
hexColorTemp = ''

for hexColorPart in hexString:
    a += 1

    if a < 7:
        hexColorTemp += hexColorPart
    elif a == 7:
        a = 0
        hexColors.append(hexColorTemp)
        hexColorTemp = ''

for fullColor in hexColors:
    if tur.xcor() < 370:
        print(tur.pos())
        print(fullColor)
        print()
        tur.pencolor('#' + fullColor)
        tur.pendown()
        tur.fd(1)
        tur.penup()
    elif tur.xcor() == 370:
        startY -= 1
        tur.goto(startX, startY)
        print(tur.pos())
        print(fullColor)
        print()
        tur.pencolor('#' + fullColor)
        tur.pendown()
        tur.fd(1)
        tur.penup()

tur.mainloop()
```

P.S. In the debugging program, the display of the current color and the position of the brush is enabled.

I tried to write 6 instead of 7, in 20 and 22 lines of code, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you reach `a==7` you don't do `hexColorTemp += hexColorPart` so you miss the current `hexColorPart`

You always need to append `hexColorPart`, then if the length is 6, save it and clear `hexColorTemp`

```
hexColors = []
hexColorTemp = ''
for hexColorPart in hexString:
    hexColorTemp += hexColorPart
    if len(hexColorTemp) == 6:
        hexColors.append(hexColorTemp)
        hexColorTemp = ''
```

But the nicest way to get based-length groups is to slice like

```
hexColors = [hexString[i:i + 6] for i in range(0, len(hexString), 6)]
```